# Consultas fetch a node / expressJs

Tags: nodejs, formularios, express, fetch

Estoy intentando enviar los datos de un formulario a través de fetch, necesito enviar estos valores al servidor (node.js / expressJs) pero no lo consigo, el problema que me arroja la cnosola es algo relacionado con los headers.

Los valores de email y contraseña los capturo con un formulario HTML y los envío al servidor. Envío además el valor de un token almacenado en el local storage, esto con ayuda de javascript.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/login" enctype="text/plain">

    <div class="form-label-group m-3">
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
    </div>
     
    <div class="form-label-group m-3">
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Contraseña">
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <button id="botonIngreso" type="submit">Iniciar Sesion</button>
    </div>                   
</form>
```

Con javascript activo el escuchador de eventos sobre el boton para ejecutar la función que llama al fetch:

```
    botonIngreso.addEventListener ("click", (evento)=>{
    evento.preventDefault();
    let botonIngreso = document.getElementById("botonIngreso");
    let inputEmail = document.getElementById("inputEmail");
    let inputPassword = document.getElementById("inputPassword");


    localStorage.setItem('token', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJub21icmVVc3VhcmlvIjoiSW50ZW50bzMiLCJhcGVsbGlkb1VzdWFyaW8iOiJpbnRlbnRvMyIsImVtYWlsVXN1YXJpbyI6Im51ZXZvQHByb3llY3RvLmNvbSIsImNvbnRyYXNlbmEiOiIxMjM0NSIsImlkX3RpcG9Sb2wiOjEsImlhdCI6MTYwNDk3ODU4MX0.m4DVs_UCloN44xTPzfI9fxnS0d_KarDKyiBDnDvDQQ8');
    var token = localStorage.getItem( 'token' );
    var usuario = inputEmail.value;
    var contrasena = inputPassword.value;

    const peticion = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }),
        body: new URLSearchParams({
          'user': usuario,
          'password': contrasena,
          'token': token
        })
    }

  let miPeticion = new Request( "http://localhost:3000/login", peticion );

   fetch(miPeticion, {credentials: 'include'}) 
       .then( (respuesta)=>{
           console.log(respuesta)
           if (respuesta.ok){
               return respuesta.json()
           }
       }).then((respuestaJson)=>{
            console.log(respuestaJson)
       }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
```

En Express valido el token:

```
        const validarToken = (req, res, next)=>{
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization;
        const token = req.body.token;
        console.log(token.split(' ')[1])
        JWT.verify(token.split(' ')[1], process.env.secreto);
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(401).json('token no válido');
    }
}
```

y consulto el endpoint:

```
        conexiones.app.post("/login", validacionesUsuarios.usuarioExistenteIngreso, (req, res)=>{
    
    const {emailUsuario, contrasena} =req.body;
    conexiones.sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE emailUsuario=? AND contrasena=?",
    {
        replacements: [emailUsuario, contrasena],
        type:conexiones.sequelize. QueryTypes. SELECT
    }).then((respuesta)=>{
        if(respuesta.length>0){
            console.log(respuesta)
            let usuario = respuesta[0]

            const payload = {
                nombreUsuario : usuario.nombreUsuario,
                apellidoUsuario : usuario.apellidoUsuario,
                emailUsuario: usuario.emailUsuario,
                contrasena: usuario.contrasena,
                id_tipoRol: usuario.id_tipoRol,
            };
            const Token = JWT.sign(payload, process.env.secreto);

            res.status(200).json(Token)

        }else{
            res.status(400).json("No tienes axeso a la plataforma")
        }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json(error)
    });
});
```

Les agradezco mucho si me pueden colaborar, llevo varias horas con esto y no lo he logrado!!

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando una mezcla de `URLEncoded` `body` con `application/json` `Content-Type`

Tenés que cambiar `ÙRLSearchParams(...)` por `JSON.stringify(...)`

Aparte del lado del servidor tenes que usar el modulo `body-parser` para parsear el `body`

```javascript
const { json } = require("body-parser");
app.use(json())
```